# How to set a variable when using Pandas' read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

"test.csv" has columns "col_a", "col_b" and "col_c".

```
#import pandas import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./data/test.csv',header=0,dtype={'col_a':object,'col_b':object,'col_c':object})
```

This code can work well. But I would like to change the code using the variable "key_word" as follow, but it cannot work well.Why? How should I modify this code?

```
#import pandas import pandas as pd
key_word='col_a':object,'col_b':object,'col_c':object
df = pd.read_csv('./data/test.csv',header=0,dtype={key_word})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `key_word` a dictionary by initializing it like this:

```
key_word={'col_a':object,'col_b':object,'col_c':object}
```

that should do the trick. right now it cannot possibly work since you produce a massive syntax error without curly brackets.

Comment: Dear Cut7er, Thank you!

Comment: if the answer helped you solve your problem, you can vote it up or accept it as the "right" answer :-)

Comment: Dear Cut7er
  Following to your comment, I could get the right answer using the dictionary.
  Thank you very much.
Regards, Hiroyasu Takeda